# Angular2 timer with dynnamic image url - Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a timer that loops from 1 - 3 and on each loop I would like to use the number to load an image with that number in the url.

**Component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from "@angular/core";
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

    @Component({
        selector: 'animated-content',
        template: require('./animated-content.template.html')
    })

    export class AnimatedContentComponent implements OnInit{

        highlightedItem = 1;
        private sub: Subscription;

        constructor(){

        }

        ngOnInit(){
            let timer = Observable.timer(1,2000);
            this.sub = timer.subscribe( t => this.startContentCycle(t))
        }

        private startContentCycle(highlightedItem) {
            if (this.highlightedItem === 3) {
                this.highlightedItem = 1;
            } else {
                this.highlightedItem++;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Template**

```
    <img [src]="/assets/signup-step{{highlightedItem}}.gif" alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

In assets the images are `signup-step1.gif`, `signup-step2.gif` and `signup-step3.gif`.

I'm getting this error:

> 'Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax is this:

```
  <img [src]="'/assets/signup-step' + highlightedItem + '.gif'" alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

You can't use interpolation and data binding at the same time.

Comment: yes, @OP: in cases like these, better extract that stuff in a function - this will allow you to use TS/ES6 string interpolation and make the html clearer